# How i create crontab by php code on linux like task on window

Tags: php, linux, scheduled-tasks, cron

i try to set time to run product update iventory every day week or once

in window i can use exec($command,$output); to set in Task Scheduler 
( Command code is

```
$command  = 'schtasks ';
$command .= '/create ';
switch ($TaskType){
                case 'once':
                    $command .=  = '/sc once ';
                    break;
                case 'daily':
                    $command .=  = '/sc daily ';
                    $command .= .= '/mo '.$Recur.' '; //(every 1 day 2 days or more)
                    break;
                case 'weekly':
                    $command .= '/sc weekly ';
                    $command .= .= '/mo '.$Recur.' '; //(every 1 week 2 weeks or more)
                    $command .= '/d '.$this->getWeeklyday().' '; // sun,mon,tue
                    break;
        } 
$command .= $this->getScheduleTaskName(); //once00001 /daily0000001 / weekly000002
$date = new DateTime($this->getDateTrigger());
$command .= '/sd {$date->format('m/d/Y')} '; 
$command .= '/st {$date->format('H:i')} '; 
$command .= '/tr "C:\pathto\php.exe pathto\shell\target.php -id '.$id.'" ';
$command .= '/f';
```

)

i write code crontab for daily and weekly on linux to use now but i don't know how to set this code by php like this (and i don't know how to set once)

(and can i delete custom crontab by php code?)